# Multi-Tenancy whit JWT autentication and validation of user for tenant

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, multi-tenant

I have a project running with JWT authentication, it works, but now I need to implement Multi-Tenancy using the following approach:

[image: Shared Database and Shared Schema]

**Requirements:**

1. A user can have access to one or more tenants
2. Access permissions are defined by user and tenant
3. Getting subdomain through `@RequestAttribute` in requests
4. Generate the token containing the tenant ID (subdomain).
5. Validate the tenant on all requests

**Implemented:**

- Created JWT Autentication.
- Created `TenantInterceptor`.
- Getting subdomain using `@RequestAttribute` on requests.
- Created `existsByUsernameAndSubdomain` validation.

I'm having trouble implementing this new feature, can you point me to an implementation example or tutorial that can help me?

I thank you for your help!

Below are my classes or if you prefer clone on **[GitHub](https://github.com/clejton/multi-tenancy)**!

**My classes**

***Models:***

```js
/** ERole **/
    public enum ERole {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_MODERATOR,
    ROLE_ADMIN
}

/** Role **/
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private ERole name;
}

/** Tenant **/
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tenants",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "subdomain", name = "un_subdomain")
        })
public class Tenant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String subdomain;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

}

/** User **/
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username", name = "un_username")
        })
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

//    Remove
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_users_roles_users1"))},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_users_roles_roles1"))})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

//    Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<UserTenant> tenants = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

}

/** UserTenant **/
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users_tenants",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "user_id", name = "un_user_id"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "tenant_id", name = "un_tenant_id")
        })
public class UserTenant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
            nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "fk_users_tenants_user1"))
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id",
            nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "fk_users_tenants_tenant1"))
    @JsonBackReference
    private Tenant tenant;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_tenants_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_tenant_id",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_users_tenants_user_tenant1"))},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_users_tenants_roles1"))})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

***Payloads:***

```js
/** LoginRequest **/
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LoginRequest {
    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

}

/** SignupRequest **/
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SignupRequest {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String password;
    private Set<String> role;

}

/** JwtResponse **/
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JwtResponse {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private List<String> roles;
    private String tokenType = "Bearer";
    private String accessToken;

    public JwtResponse(String accessToken, Long id, String username,
                       List<String> roles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

}

/** MessageResponse **/
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MessageResponse {
    private String message;

    public MessageResponse(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

***Repositories:***

```js
/** RoleRepository **/
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Optional<Role> findByName(ERole name);
}

/** UserRepository **/
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);

}

/** UserTenantRepository **/
@Repository
public interface UserTenantRepository extends JpaRepository<UserTenant, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT ut FROM UserTenant ut WHERE ut.user.username = :username AND ut.tenant.subdomain = :subdomain ")
    Optional<UserTenant> findByUserAndSubdomain(String username, String subdomain);

    @Query("SELECT " +
            "CASE WHEN COUNT(ut) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END " +
            "FROM UserTenant ut " +
            "WHERE ut.user.username = :username " +
            "AND ut.tenant.subdomain = :subdomain ")
    Boolean existsByUsernameAndSubdomain(String subdomain, String username);

}
```

***Services:***

```js
/** AuthService **/
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public JwtResponse authenticateUser(String subdomain, LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        System.out.println(subdomain);

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
        System.out.println(authentication);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new JwtResponse(jwt,
                userDetails.getId(),
                userDetails.getUsername(),
                roles);
    }

    @Transactional
    public MessageResponse registerUser(SignupRequest signUpRequest) {

        // Create new user's account
        User user = new User(
                signUpRequest.getUsername(),
                encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                    case "admin":
                        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(adminRole);
                        break;
                    case "mod":
                        Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(modRole);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!");
    }

}

/** UserDetailsImpl **/
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Long id;

    private final String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    private final String password;

    private final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public UserDetailsImpl(Long id, String username, String password,
                           Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new UserDetailsImpl(
                user.getId(),
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id);
    }
}

/** UserDetailsServiceImpl **/
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserTenantRepository userTenantRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));


        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }

}
```

***Controller***

```js
/** AuthController **/
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserTenantRepository userTenantRepository;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(
            @RequestAttribute String subdomain,
            @Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest
    ) {
        if (!userTenantRepository.existsByUsernameAndSubdomain(subdomain, loginRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Unauthorized: This username and tenant is not authorized!"));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authService.authenticateUser(subdomain, loginRequest));
    }


    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authService.registerUser(signUpRequest));
    }
}
```

***JWT:***

```js
/** AuthEntryPointJwt **/
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized: incorrect username or password");
    }

}

/** AuthTokenFilter **/
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
            , FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                String serverName = request.getServerName();
                String subdomain = serverName.substring(0, serverName.indexOf("."));

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                System.out.println(userDetails);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/** JwtUtils **/
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${example.app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${example.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

***Utils:***

```js
/** TenantInterceptor **/
public class TenantInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        String serverName = request.getServerName();
        String tenantId = serverName.substring(0, serverName.indexOf("."));

        request.setAttribute("subdomain", tenantId);

        return true;
    }
}

/** WebSecurityConfig **/
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    final
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private final AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/auth/**",
                        "/v3/api-docs/**",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/configuration/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new TenantInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by modifying the `loadUserByUsername` method in the `UserDetailsServiceImpl`.

See the implementation details on **[GitHub](https://github.com/clejton/multi-tenancy)**!

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserTenantRepository userTenantRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        // Getting subdomain from request attributes
        HttpServletRequest request =
                ((ServletRequestAttributes) Objects.requireNonNull(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()))
                        .getRequest();

        String serverName = request.getServerName();
        String subdomain = serverName.substring(0, serverName.indexOf("."));
        UserTenant userTenant = userTenantRepository.findByUserAndSubdomain(username, subdomain)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(
                        "UserTenant Not Found with username: " + username + " and " + subdomain));

        // Getting Rules from the UserTenant
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = userTenant.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new UserDetailsImpl(
                userTenant.getUser().getId(),
                userTenant.getUser().getUsername(),
                userTenant.getUser().getPassword(),
                authorities
        );
    }
}
```

**Inserts in Database**

```
INSERT INTO roles(id, name)
VALUES (1 ,'ROLE_USER'),
       (2, 'ROLE_MODERATOR'),
       (3, 'ROLE_ADMIN');

INSERT INTO tenants (id, name, subdomain)
VALUES (1, 'Tenant 1', 'tenant1'),
       (2, 'Tenant 2', 'tenant2');

# user, password
# user1, user1
# user2, user2
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password)
VALUES (1, 'user1', '$2a$10$wFMJLxdXKGRa8lJO6k2DAOnW9HstAPoHecXUNkDyYNeaNnZJAz.hy'),
       (2, 'user2', '$2a$10$Z9/wLkmf5IwfjJqIQU6X.OBFg3TCBUyk3bdfgkGjU0.HI5kVibZxG');

INSERT INTO users_tenants (id,  tenant_id, user_id)
VALUES (1, 1, 1),
       (2, 2, 2);

INSERT INTO users_tenants_roles (user_tenant_id,  role_id)
VALUES (1, 2),
       (1, 3),
       (2, 1);


INSERT INTO items (id,  tenant_id, name)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Product 1 in Tenant 1'),
       (2, 1, 'Product 2 in Tenant 1'),
       (3, 2, 'Product 1 in Tenant 2'),
       (4, 2, 'Product 2 in Tenant 2');
```

**Validations in Postman**

*Created token variable in Postman:*
[image: Validations in Postman]

*Set token value in Postman variable:*
[image: Set token value in Postman variable]

*Added Authorization variable in requests headers:*
[image: Added Authorization variable in requests headers]

*Validating if the domain exists in sign in:*
[image: Validating if the domain exists in sign in]

*Validating user access permission on tenant:*
[image: Validating user access permission on tenant:]

*Authorized login:*
[image: Authorized login]

*Getting items of tenant1:*
[image]

*Trying to get tenant2 list of items without being logged in tenant2 and having access permissions:*
[image: Trying to get tenant2]

*Logging in with user2 in tenant2:*
[image: Logging in with user2 in tenant2]

*Getting items list tenant2*
[image: Getting items list tenant2]

**Trying to get tenant1 list of items without being logged in tenant1 and having access permissions:**
[image: Trying to get tenant1]